# PHP date and time from an xml import

Tags: php, xml, datetime

I have an xml file where the date stored in this format:

`<sun rise="2014-05-30T02:51:30" set="2014-05-30T18:31:22"/>`

My php process this value to a variable named $sunrise

> 2014-05-30T02:51:30

But my timezone is +2 so I have to add 2 more hours.

The only problem with this its just a string. 
I dont have any idea to how to convert it to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got the time inside that element `(2014-05-30T02:51:30)` you could just use `strtotime()` or alternatively, you could also use `DateTime` + `DateInterval` to add 2 more hours. Consider this example:

```
$sunrise = '2014-05-30T02:51:30';

$date = new DateTime($sunrise);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// outputs: 2014-05-30 04:51:30

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($sunrise . ' +2 hours'));
// outputs: 2014-05-30 04:51:30
```

Comment: Thank you! (the second one is the best for me)